# ALB listener requires at least one targetGroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I made an `ApplicationLoadBalancer` in a CDK project and want to use this `ApplicationLoadBalancer` from multiple projects.

For example, I have three cdk project `maincdk`,`app1cdk`,`app2cdk`

- making an `ALB` and a `listener`(main-listener, port 80) in `maincdk`
- in `app1cdk`, add targetGroup(like ECS) to main-listener
- in `app2cdk` add targetGroup(like ECS) to main-listener
- each access is port 80, but I can switch by domain name.

However, in `maincdk`:

```js
    const lb = new elb.ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, "lb", {
      vpc: vpc,
      loadBalancerName : "main-lb",
      internetFacing: true,
      vpcSubnets: vpc.selectSubnets({ subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC }),
      securityGroup: adminLbSg
    });

    const listener = lb.addListener("main-listener", { port: 80 });
```

this error occurs:

```
    [CommonLbStack/lb/main-listener] Listener needs at least one default action or target group (call addTargetGroups or addAction)
```

It says that the `listener` should have at least one `TargetGroup`.

I added a dummy action like this, but the same error occurs:

```js
    listener.addAction('Fixed', {
      priority: 1,
      conditions: [
        elb.ListenerCondition.pathPatterns(['/ok']),
      ],
      action: elb.ListenerAction.fixedResponse(200, {
        messageBody: 'OK',
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says you need at least one:

- default action
- or target group

Since you don't want to add a TargetGroup from `maincdk`, why not add a *default* action? The fixed action you have above isn't a default action. Try something like:

```js
listener.addAction('DefaultAction', {
  action: elbv2.ListenerAction.fixedResponse(404, {
    contentType: elbv2.ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN,
    messageBody: 'Cannot route your request; no matching project found.',
  }),
});
```

Then you can layer conditional rules on top of that from the `app1cdk` and `app2cdk` projects to route to those projects based on whatever criteria you need -- path, hostname, etc.

See: "[Default Rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#rule-action-types)" on the Listener Configuration docs.

Comment: Thank you very much It's the best practice for this purpose just adding default action.